# where to refer to?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, cross-posting, se-sites

I was helping Sadache with his question [Function to predict processing service overload](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/813661/function-to-predict-processing-service-overload)

After giving some hints of things he needed to look into before the question could even be answered . I decided to flag it as "as unclear what you're asking "

whereup  Sadache  replied "meaning that this is not a place where I can ask questions about understanding problems? is there a stack exchange community for that? "

The question is not really about mathematics but about mathematical/ statistical modeling, which stack exchange is for that ?

There is a mathematical modeling tag but is the question even enough developed / specific for that?